# Moishezon manifold with vanishing $b_2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Does there exist a closed  [Moishezon manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moishezon_manifold)  with zero second Betti number?

Comment: $M = \mathrm{pt}$ works, though you're probably looking for a positive-dimensional example.

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ has positive dimension, the answer is *no*. In fact, the following holds:

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a compact manifold such that $a(X)= n >0$. Then $b_2(X)>0$.

The proof is essentially based on the well-known fact that the assumption $a(X)=n$ implies that $X$ is a bimeromorphic modification of a projective manifold. Look at Lemma 1.4 of the paper

*Campana, Frédéric; Demailly, Jean-Pierre; Peternell, Thomas*, [**The algebraic dimension of compact complex threefolds with vanishing second Betti number**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1000313214795), Compos. Math. 112, No. 1, 77-91 (1998). [ZBL0910.32032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0910.32032).

Comment: Note: $a(X)$ is the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions of $X$ over $\mathbf{C}$ — and $X$ is implicitly assumed connected.

Comment: it seems there was a typo in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11179

Comment: though it does not affect the validity of the answer